# Vuejs 3 append dynamic component to dom with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to pass a dynamic component (ChildA) to another component (ChildB) and then append the ChildA component to the dom from ChildB via jquery.. Is there any way to make this work? I know this is not not the best solution but the real case is much more complicated and i think the easiest way would be if i got this to work.

Parent

```
<template>
  <ChildB :component="component" />
</template>
import ChildA from './ChildA.vue';
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return { component: ChildA } 
  };
</script>
```

ChildA

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>I am Child A</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>
```

ChildB

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="child"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['component'],
  mounted() {
  $('#child').append(this.component);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is most likely XY problem. The use of jQuery rings a bell; some obsolete coding practice is used that doesn't work well with modern frameworks. FWIW, this is what roughly portals/teleports do but in a clean way. Consider addressing your real problem instead of supposedly wrong solution. If it's complex then it probably could be simplified.

Comment: Totally agree with what @EstusFlask says. With that in mind, could you explain exactly what you want to achieve? Why do you want to add another component like this? Do you have many different components to choose from or just two?

Comment: [Dynamic Components](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#dynamic-components)